# Database access error issues, SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I managed to solve my last problem but now I ran into this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.eazymocky/com.example.eazymocky.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

My `cursors` are however initialized and it seems this shows up when attempting to populate my controls:

My code is below:

```
public LocationEntity getLocationEntity(long locId) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.tableLocations + " WHERE "
            + idColumn + " = " + locId;

    Log.e(LOG, query);
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    LocationEntity location = new LocationEntity();
    location.setLocationId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(idColumn)));
    location.setLocationName(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationName)));
    location.setLocationIcon(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationIcon)));
    location.setLocationAddress(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationAddress)));
    location.setLocationCity(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationCity)));
    location.setLocationZIP(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationZIP)));
    location.setLocationCountry(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationCountry)));
    location.setFavoriteFlag(cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(locationIsFavorite)));

    return location;
}
```

Any help you may provide would be more than welcome! :)

Comment: Are you sure that you have location with the id you are looking for?

Comment: It should be in there. Populating databases on Android has proven to be a bit of a problem for me. I can't access the database directly to put data in.

Comment: Put the whole code for initializing `LocationEntity` into IF, and change if into this: `if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())`. And try to debug the application. It looks like you dont have location with specified id.

Comment: Do you know of any way to access sqlite databases on mobile devices? I am testing directly on device due to the emulator being rather slow. I tried your suggestion but the problem seems to persist.

Comment: You can copy your database file onto the SD Card and then use it on computer. I was doing that for testing.

Comment: Maybe you can first list the database. `"SELECT * FROM " + dbHelper.tableLocations;`

Comment: The thing is it worked earlier. I had one location in the database.Then came a database upgrade I added some new tables and it all fell apart. Unfortunately my phone did not come with an SD Card default and I did not buy one yet.

Comment: Did you update your database version number when you added the new tables / columns?

Comment: Yep I did do that. Always do when I make changes to the database.

Comment: With another DB Version change it seemed to work. I guess I just need to populate the database.